# Is there a way to copy all subdirectories matching a pattern?

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I'm running a script post-build that copies binary results to a common results directory. It roughly looks like this:

```
...
copy /Y trunk\foo\bin\Release\* out
copy /Y trunk\bar\bin\Release\* out
copy /Y trunk\whee\bin\Release\* out
...
```

Since there are a lot of projects involved I'd like to abbreviate this script and simply copy all `*/bin/Release/*` files. How could I do this?

(Of course I could just write a small program but I'm interested in a general solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CD trunk
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%A IN (`dir /b /a:d /s ^| FIND /I "\bin\release"`) DO (
 COPY /Y "%%A\*" "out"
)
```

change directory to trunk folder; loop over the output of dir|find, which it grabs a list of all subdirectories and only targets the ones containing \bin\release in the pathname; copy all files contained in the release folders to out.